# Is it possible to use React together with typescript without transpiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to use `React` together wit `TypeScript` in a simple way?

I want to write my components in `TypeScript` to have type-safety. The few tutorials I've found so far do always need to have babel-loader, ts-loader and webpack running to make it work.
In my tsconfig I can set "jsx" to either ("preserve","react" or "react-native") but I don't see how to go on from there or which one I should use.

At the end I would like to have a jsx-file which I can reference from my cshtml `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/TypeScript/MyComponent.jsx")"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the full features of ES6, then the answer is NO. It'll be high time since most of the users upgrade their system so that all ES6/Typescript code runs properly.

Comment: And how about if I don't want all the features of ES6?